# Reduces dataframe based on maximum and duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to reduce this dataframe with multiple rows with the same name, but with different values to a dataframe containing only 1 row per name with the maximum value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"Name": "Foo", "Value": 1}, {"Name": "Foo", "Value": 3}, {"Name": "Bar", "Value": 1},{"Name": "Bar", "Value": 4}])
```

Dataframe wanted:

```
df_filtered = pd.DataFrame([{"Name": "Foo", "Value": 3}, {"Name": "Bar", "Value": 4}])
```

I started with df.groupby however it didn't feel natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort values to have the max values at the end, then take the last row per group.

```
df.sort_values(by='Value').groupby('Name', as_index=False).last()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I also tried 
```new_df = pd.DataFrame([{"Name": name, "Value": name_df["Value"].max()} for name, name_df in df.groupby("Name", axis=0)])```
However this feels not really scalable with a lot of columns